# Selenium Runs Chrome Profile But Not Rest Of Script

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
#Required Boundaries
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#Opens Chrome Profile
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("/Users/paolamohan/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome",options=options)
time.sleep(2)


#Gmail
Gmail = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gb"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a')
Gmail.click()
```

Here is my Code. I figured out how to make the Webdriver open up Chrome with my Chrome Profile but now I can't run anything else after it executes. For this simple example, I just want the script to click the little "Gmail" icon at the top right corner of Google's home page

I'm new to Python so any written code would be extremely useful!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Before you can click the button Selenium needs to open the page with `driver.get(url)`.

So you do:

```
#Required Boundaries
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#Opens Chrome Profile
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("/Users/paolamohan/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome",options=options)
time.sleep(2)

#Access Site
url = "https://google.de"
driver.get(url)

#Gmail
Gmail = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gbw"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a')
Gmail.click()
```